# Xamarin Studio locals not showing in debug

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

When I debug my iOS app in `Xamarin studio`. If I set a breakpoint and run the app it stops and shows me my `locals` and everything is great the first time.

However any time after that if I run my app it stops on the breakpoint and the `locals` list is empty.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

The only way I can get the locals to show back up is to close `Xamarin Studio` and reopen it, and then they only work for one debugging session again.

Comment: I'd suggest posting this in the XS forum - http://forums.xamarin.com/categories/xamarin-studio - it may be a bug that you should report at bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Another way to see variables values is "Immediate" pad. You can type variables names and even expressions to see it's values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response in the [Xamarin Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/12427#Comment_12427):

`This bug should be fixed in the upcoming 4.0.5 release.`

Comment: The same issue for Windows apps. Android apps work fine. That's strange that debugging Xamarin Android app on Windows is better experience than debugging a Windows app. I mean, Windows app on Windows is native, so it should provide better debugging, but in practice it is otherwise.